# How to implement push on Android 1.5?

Tags: java, android, push, push-notification

I am developing an application for android v1.5,

I need to use Push messaging service to inform users of some information. What is the best way of implementing push on the android version 1.5. If there are any example out there could you let me know. i have looked at MQTT , and i dont really understand how to use it, also dale lanes sample code only works for android phones above level 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As C2DM is probably not an option for you, have a look at [pubnub](http://pubnub.com). They offer a generous (enough) free mode for you to get going and since it's a library you import in, it should theoretically work with Android 1.5.

Another service you can look into is [Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/products/push-notifications/) - again not *C2DM* free but better than nothing.